# Need help to work with Infragistics webdatagrid

Tags: infragistics, webdatagrid

am first time working in the Infragistics webdatagrid.

So far ,I installed the trail version and binded the data(datatable) to the webdatagrid successfully .  Now i got the requirement to edit the data in that webdatagrid.

I googled it , but i  couldnt get exact and much information about it. so i stucked

If anyone worked or knows ,could you please guide me in correct direction?

thanks
karthik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit the cells in the grid you will need to add the EditingCore behavior and then add the CellEditing behavior to that.  For example:

```
<Behaviors>
    <ig:Activation />
    <ig:Selection RowSelectType="Multiple" CellClickAction="Row" />
    <ig:EditingCore>
        <Behaviors>
            <ig:CellEditing Enabled="true" >
                <EditModeActions EnableF2="true" EnableOnActive="true" MouseClick="Single" />
                <ColumnSettings>
                    <ig:EditingColumnSetting ColumnKey="CustomerID" ReadOnly="true" />
                </ColumnSettings>                               
            </ig:CellEditing>
        </Behaviors>
    </ig:EditingCore>
</Behaviors>
```

This was taken from the [Cell Editing - Basic Features](http://www.infragistics.com/samples/aspnet/data-grid/editing-rows-basic-features) online sample.